# Divergence form of the fractional Laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus

Can I write the fractional Laplacian
$$(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} u(x) : = c_{\alpha,d} 
     \mathrm{P.V.}\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{u(x) - u(y)}{|x-y|^{d+\alpha}}dy$$
in the divergence form 
$$(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2} u(x)  = \nabla \cdot J(x)$$
for some function $J$? Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The answer is yes, under some regularity assumptions for $u$.**

I will show two such representations:

1. Since $\Delta=\operatorname{div}\nabla=\nabla\cdot\nabla$ we have:

> $$ (-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}u=(-\Delta)(-\Delta)^{(\alpha-2)/2}u=
> \nabla\cdot(-\nabla((-\Delta)^{(\alpha-2)/2}u). $$

2. Another representation uses Riesz transforms.
   With the Fourier transform defined by 
   $$
   \hat{u}(\xi) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u(x)e^{-2\pi i x\cdot\xi}\, dx
   $$
   we can express the derivatives and the fractional Laplacian by
   $$
   \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_j} = (2\pi i\xi_j\hat{u})^\vee,
   \qquad
   (-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}u=((4\pi^2|\xi|^2)^{\alpha/2}\hat{u})^\vee.
   $$
   The Riesz transforms are defined by 
   $$
   R_j u = \left(-\frac{i\xi_j}{|\xi|}\hat{u}\right)^\vee
   \quad
   \text{for $j=1,2,\ldots,n$,}
   $$
   and the vector valued Riesz transform is
   $$
   Ru=\langle R_1 u,\ldots,R_n u\rangle
   $$
   Then it is easy to check that

> $$ (-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}u =
>  \nabla\cdot(R(-\Delta)^{\frac{\alpha-1}{2}}u). $$

Indeed, by taking the Fourier transform this equality reduces to
$$
(4\pi^2|\xi|^2)^{\alpha/2}=
\sum_{j=1}^n (2\pi i\xi_j)\left(-\frac{i\xi_j}{|\xi|}\right)(4\pi^2|\xi|^2)^{(\alpha-1)/2}.
$$

The Riesz transform can be expressed as the singular integral operator.

Comment: They are equivalent for u with proper regularities, right?

Comment: @KKK That is correct. Also the Fourier transform definition of $(-\Delta)^{\alpha/2}$ is equivalent with yours when $0<\alpha<2$, see last chapter in "Updated version of Harmonic Analysis" available at http://www.pitt.edu/~hajlasz/Teaching/Math2304Spring2017/m2304Spring2017.html